# INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not updating the duplicate value in PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to use the funcion `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` to insert some data in a mySQL table.
And if there's already a user registered with the same email, i want to update the values.

So I implemented the code below after searching in this discussions:
[link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407593/insert-on-duplicate-key-update), [link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673350/php-mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-not-working), and other links...

I also watched the manuals [link-4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO theElisa_signUp (name, email, telephone, user, psw, role, expire_date)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', 'not-set', '$username', '$password', '$role', '$expire_date')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE name = '$name', user ='$username', psw = '$password', expire_date = '$expire_date' ");
```

In fact, the code can correctly insert a new user.
But if I try to update a user that already exist, it creates a new record. So i have two user registered with the same email (I need to update the user if already there's the email in the table)

I hope this question respect the standards and I've already done all the researches in stackoverflow but none of the answers could help me.
So please don't mark my question as duplicate.

P.s. I'm actually a web designer with zero experience in coding and this project is beyond my capabilities. But unfortunately I have to solve this question.
Thank you.

Comment: Make the `email` column unique

Comment: What is the key for the table?

Comment: Is email column unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Duplicate Key Update same as insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert)

Comment: Hi, so probably i wass really noob in this. So now I've set the email as unique in my table (I also have a primary key as `id`, but this, for now it's not necessary).

Comment: Use parameterized queries. This is SQL injectable. It looks like you either should remove `telephone` or make its default value `not-set`.  Hopefully `psw` is hashed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column email should be UNIQUE.

```
ALTER TABLE `theElisa_signUpADD` UNIQUE (email);
```

Comment: Yes! thank you, i've done it within the mySQL table and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two queries [here's reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO theElisa_signUp (name, email, telephone, user, psw, role, expire_date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', 'not-set', '$username', '$password', '$role', '$expire_date') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '$name',");
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE theElisa_signUp SET user ='$username', psw = '$password', expire_date = '$expire_date' WHERE name = '$name' ");
```

Comment: Why would you use 2 queries? This will update the row that was just inserted.

Comment: No, this will insert new data in reference from the from the unique email. It's like how the alter command works